# VS Code V1.25 clicking on tab doesn't expand window anymore

Tags: visual-studio-code

Just upgraded to VS Code 1.25 and there has been a much needed change to the splitting of the editors. How ever with this has come a change to another behavior that I really liked and saved me a lot of clicking.

With multiple splits of the editor with tabs open in each I could click on a tab and the split would expand to make it easier to code in. That behavior no longer exists and clicking on a top only activates that tab and does not expand the split.

Is there a setting that can be set to enable the old behavior?

I hope this was clear.

I should mention that the reason this is helpful is that I use a Surface Pro much of the time and work without a mouse or the touch pad and only use the touch screen. Touching a tab was great when it would expand but now I need to either have the touch pad (hate it) or mouse available to resize the split which I'm doing all the time. Touch screen doesn't work with the resizing of a split at all and never has.

Answer (score 0):

Best solution that I have been able to find is installing a macros extension and creating a macro that in settings.json

```
"macros": {
    "focusNextGroup": [
        "workbench.action.focusNextGroup",
        "workbench.action.minimizeOtherEditors"
    ]
}
```

and a key binding

```
{
    "key": "Ctrl+alt+x",
    "command": "macros.focusNextGroup",
},
```

At least I can toggle through them now. I'm wondering now if it is possible to create an on focus event, get the group and expand it.